# Is there a way to access a block of elements in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a 2 dimensional dataframe with 1000 rows and columns. I am hoping to access blocks of the dataframe such as a square from row 100:200 and column 100:200.

[image]

Block will look like this.

Tried using a for loop in a for loop to loop through every element and append to a new df. Was far too slow and am hoping that there is a faster way within a function such as loc or iloc that I am missing.

Comment: Doesn't `df.iloc[100:200,100:200]` do the job?

Comment: cannot believe i didnt try this. i tried df.iloc[100:200][100:200]. guess i've been looking at code for too long without sleep. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

df.iloc[100:200,100:200] works. oops

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).